# Time series modeling in f#-- seq vs array vs vector vs list vs generic list

Tags: f#, time-series

If I want to make a time series type in F# to hold stock prices, which basic type should I use? We need

1. Select a subset based on time index,
2. Calculate basic statistics for a subset like mean, STD or for several subsets like correlations,
3. Append item for new data and fast update statistics or technical indicators,
4. Do linear regression between time series, etc

I have read that `array` has a better performance, `seq` has a smaller memory footnote, `list` is better for adding items and F# `vector` is easier for certain math calculation. To balance all the trade offs, how would you model a stock price time series in f#? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a concrete representation you can choose either array or list or some other .NET colllection type. A sequence `seq<'T>` is an abstract type and both array and list are automatically also sequences - this means that when you write some code that works with sequences, it will work with any concrete data type (array, list or any other .NET collection).

So, when writing **data processing**, you can use `Seq` by default (as it gives you great flexibility - it doesn't matter what concrete representation you use) and then optimize some operations to use the concrete representation (whatever that will be) if you need something to run faster.

Regarding the **concrete representation** - I think the crucial question is whether you want to add elements without changing original data structure (immutable list or array used in an immutable way) or whether you want to mutate the data structure (e.g. use some mutable .NET collection).

If you need to add new items freuqently then you can either use immutable list (which supports appending elements to front) or a mutable collection (array won't do as it cannot be resized).

- If you're working on a more sophisticated system, I would recommend taking a look at `ObservableCollection<T>` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)). This is a collection that automatically notifies you when it is changed. In response to the notification, you could update your statistics (it also tells you which elements were added, so you don't need to recalculate everything). However, F# doesn't have any libraries for working with this type, so you'll need to write a lot of things yourself.
- If you're adding data only rarely or adding them in larger groups, you could use array (and allocate new array each time you add items). If you have only relatively small number of items in the collection, you could use lists (where adding item is easy).

For numerical calculations, the F# PowerPack (and types like vector) offer only quite limitied set of features, so you may need to look at some thrid party libraries. [Extreme optimizations](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/) is a commercial library with some F# examples and [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) is an open source alternative.

Otherwise, it is difficult to give any concrete advice - can you add some more details about your system? (e.g. how large the data set is, how many items need to be added how often etc...)

Comment: I don't think the mutable vs immutable question is "crucial".  Folks use arrays in an immutable fashion all the time, just to get the perf of arrays (would that .NET had a readonly array type!), so I think other pragmatics are a higher concern than mutability.

Comment: @Brian - yes you're absolutely right. In fact, I was considering array more as _immutable_ because you cannot add elements (and was assuming that historical data do not change so elements won't be mutated)! I clarified the answer.